# Azure AD B2C date attribute without Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need users to enter a date when signing-up or editing their profile in Azure AD B2C. Is there any way to do this without using Custom Policies?

I see two options:

1. Use a string extension attribute with a text input. But you cannot do client-side validation...
2. Use 3x string extension attributes (day, month, year) with 3x single-select drop-down inputs. I think this is the way I will need to do it.

Is there a simpler way? Am I missing something?

Why not use Custom Policies? This is the only functionality I am missing using the built-in policies, so it seems like overkill to introduce the additional complexity of getting everything working with Custom Policies, just to get a valid date. Plus Custom Policies are in preview at the time of asking, so are subject to change etc.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a [question on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/800d1c51-dac8-49cb-bbd3-00682f8318a9/azure-b2c-date-claim-without-custom-policies?forum=WindowsAzureAD) to see if I could get an answer there.

To sum it up, you need to use Custom Policies.

My concern regarding using features in Public Preview was addressed like so:

> We recommend built-in policies for most scenario's. However, for specific requirement (scenario) built-in policies may not fetch you the actual results. In that situation, you have to use custom policies. Yes, you're right, Microsoft does not recommend using preview features in production environment. It is good to be cautious and follow the recommendations.